# Is this question a give me teh codez or a legitimate question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I think the javascript tag gets a lot of "Here is what I need" questions because there are a lot of beginner programmers using javascript (especially jquery), and they get stuck.

But when they get stuck, should they ask why their code wasn't working, or should they just ask for the solution so that 10 people can spend 20 minutes doing their work?

Here is a very good example: [How to select only the first level children in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370465/how-to-select-only-the-first-level-children-in-jquery)

These type of questions come by the dozens daily.

*edit*

Also, what, if any, type of route does the new closing options have for these types of questions, is this off topic?

Comment: I like how there are so many answers even though no one seems to know what OP *really* wants.

Comment: And a ridiculous number of self deletions as well...

Comment: I gotta be honest: that question is really **unclear**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A good question should have *both* the actual requirements of the problem being solved as well as the OP's attempt at a solution.  A question missing *either* is incomplete.

If you don't have any attempt given, or any demonstration of effort at all (i.e. clear research being done, an English description of high level attempts made that they have determined aren't an option, etc.), then it's just a gimme teh codes.  The most applicable close reason would be:

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

A question that has a code dump without an explanation of what the actual requirements that code is meant to meet, or what problems they are having with that code, would be closed as:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Both of these are new sub-reasons of "off topic".

Answer (score 8):

The metric for closing such questions is this: does the OP demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved?

If you wish to vote to close, select "Off-Topic," and choose the *"questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"* reason.